# Column number where it contains certain text?

Tags: excel, formula

Is there a formula in Excel that returns the value of a row that's under a specific header?

For example, my current sheet looks something like this.

```
Pet    Cost (£)    Age

Car      12         5
Dog      11         7
Rabbit   13         9
Snake     5         3

Pet    Cost ($)    Age

Car      10         5
Dog      13         7
Rabbit   16         9
Snake     8         3
```

If I want to pull out the first figure for Rabbit that is under the `Cost ($)` header, how do I go about it? And then for the second figure that is on that row.

I realise I can do it with INDEX/MATCH, but i'm not sure how to specify an instance or one that occurs under a certain header.

Answer (score 0):

**First Case:**
If you have the simple scheme show, you can find the second value for Rabbit, using:

```
=SMALL(IF(A:A="Rabbit";ROW(A:A));2)      Inserted with Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

To have the Index, and:

```
=INDEX(B1:B21;D2)
```

To have the value...

**Second Case:**
If you want to use the Header, for the first, use:

```
=INDEX(B1:B21;MATCH("Rabbit";INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Cost ($)";B1:B21)&":A9999")))
```

**Third Case:**
If you want to use the Header, because you can have more that one **Rabbit** in each header, Use:

```
=SMALL(IF(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH("Cost ($)";B1:B21) & ":A9999")="Rabbit";ROW(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH("Cost ($)";B1:B21) & ":A9999")));1)
```

for the first, and:

```
=SMALL(IF(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH("Cost ($)";B1:B21) & ":A9999")="Rabbit";ROW(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH("Cost ($)";B1:B21) & ":A9999")));2)
```

for the second ...
Inserted with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Comment: =SMALL(IF(A:A="Rabbit";ROW(A:A));2) You should avoid using entire column references within array formulas. Unlike e.g. SUMIF(S)/COUNTIF(S), array formulas calculate over all cells within the referenced range, whether beyond the last non-empty cell in that range or not, so  this formula is being forced to calculate over all one million-plus rows.

Comment: If you have one million of row, it's correct...The range can be set. Obviusly It's not necessary to use all the column, I don't know the entity of the datasheet. Ten rows ?

Comment: Agreed that the range can be set, of course. But it might not be "obvious" to an OP visiting a forum that it's not necessary to keep the entire column reference, especially if they've seen many uses of it before (e.g. in SUMIF(S), COUNTIF(S)) and so presumed it's perfectly fine in an array formula as well. Just because we don't know the number of rows in the OP's dataset doesn't mean that we should just use A:A - why not use e.g. A1:A1000 and let the OP decide if that's large enough?

Comment: I do not understand why do you stare so much, if you want to change edits and changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Pets listed in A2:A100 and headers in B1:Z1 you can use this "array formula" to get the value at the intersection of the nth instance of "Rabbit" in the [first] column named cost:

=INDEX(INDEX(B2:Z100,0,MATCH("cost",B1:Z1,0)),SMALL(IF(A2:A100="Rabbit",ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2)+1),**n**))

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Replace n with the required instance number